# how to install Rosdep for electric ROS in Ubuntu?

Tags: rosdep, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to install Rosdep for electric ROS in Ubuntu?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35005/how-to-install-rosdep-for-electric-ros-in-ubuntu?/) by [SHAKIMCA](https://answers.ros.org/users/2068/shakimca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Follow the [install instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu) for electric. Rosdep is not broken out in electric.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2